# htaccess redirect 301 to form https://www.domain.pl

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I tryied many potential solutions for htaccess to achieve form https://www.

and most of these solutions get good results only for three from four scenarios:

```
http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
https://example.com -> https://example.com - ERROR !
```

Now my .htaccess looks like below:

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.medconnect.pl/$1 [R=301,L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Where I make a mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked out on my site. You can check it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It rewrites all requestes for your site made for http (with or without www), for `https://www.example.com/`